# Assign a picture to a page (WordPress - PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to assign a picture via PHP to a page. I've googled already but just found something like this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/

Does anyone have an idea how I can assign a picture to a page via PHP?

Furthermore the picture has to be integrated via URL and not be downloaded in my media library and not be applied from there.

I'd be grateful about some helpful answers.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. What does your code look like, and where is the image?

Comment: I have the URL of the image. But I'm searching for a hook to assign a picture from a URL to a post in WordPress

Comment: What I mean is this here: How can I set that via PHP?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzLxINxZFzovamIxN0RKMTRvNWc